# When a user chooses to be notified of answers by email are they notified if they question is migrated?

Tags: discussion, migration, email-notification

If a question asker clicks to be notified of answers by email, then someone migrates their question...

1. Are they notified by email of the migration?
2. Do they receive email notifications of answers on the new site if they aren't registered there?

Comment: I know when the asker logs back on to the initial site, they will receive a banner notice, but I'm not sure about emails. Probably not, though, as I don't remember anything like it ever being announced.

Answer (score 1):

You do not get a email about the migration but you do get a notice on the site.

Regrading about the new site if I am not registed you can link the two accounts and if you have more then 200 rep on one of them you get a 100 rep bonus.

Comment: My concern is people that ask a question expecting to be notified by email of answers.  They may not come back to the site until they receive that email at which point they will have no way of knowing that there may be an answer waiting for them on the site their question has been migrated to.

Comment: Yes but users like me check at least weekly of there answers.